# How to differentiate between manual added steps and sensor recorded steps in Google Fit Api

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am using Google Fit Api in my project to get user's daily steps. But the problem is, user can enter the steps manually by adding the activities. And when i retrieve the daily steps, Google Fit Api also returns the steps which were added manually. 
Is there any way to differentiate between manually added steps and sensor recorded steps.

Comment: You can try checking out these similar threads: [32119448](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119448/google-fit-api-filter-manually-added-activities), [31451851](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451851/how-to-identify-google-fit-activity-is-entered-manually-or-tracked-by-sensor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how i solved this issue.

```
   final DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .read(googleFitUtils.getEstimatedSteps())
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    DataReadResult dataReadResult =
            Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mGoogleApiFitnessClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    DataSet stepData = dataReadResult.getDataSet(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);

    int totalSteps = 0;

    for (DataPoint dp : stepData.getDataPoints()) {
        for(Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
            int steps = dp.getValue(field).asInt();
            if (!"user_input".equals(dp.getOriginalDataSource().getStreamName()))
                totalSteps += steps;
        }
    }
```

First Point - > Before i was getting the total steps using

```
Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal
```

which returns one data point with total daily steps. 
Second Point - > Then i changed the way to get the daily steps using

```
Fitness.HistoryApi.readData
```

It returns array of data points with the chunks of daily steps. Each data point has a property of

```
dp.getOriginalDataSource().getStreamName()
```

which returns you the type, either steps were recorded by sensor or it was a use input. 
That's how you can filter the user input steps to avoid steps hack in your application.

Comment: Does googleFitUtils.getEstimatedSteps() returns also DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the example given in the Google Fit documentation states that you can get the base daily steps total of your device by using [this method](https://developers.google.com/fit/scenarios/record-steps).

> Your app can record the user's step count by using the [Recording
>   API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/RecordingApi)
>   to create a subscription to the `DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE`
>   data type

In your case, you are getting the aggregate data which is a combination of the sensor recorded steps and the data extracted using the [History API](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history).

Try to check out the [essential Google Fit API's](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/) that you will be needing:

- [Sensors API](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/sensors)
- [Recording API](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/record)
- [History API](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history)
- [Sessions API](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/using-sessions)
- [Goals API](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/goals)
- [Bluetooth Low Energy API](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/ble-sensors)
- Config API