# Google Fit Sensors / Recording vs History

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

Using the Google Fit History Api I would like to differentiate between user entered steps and device steps (recorded by the device sensors).

I have seen and tested many posted solutions but none that remain valid in the latest api.

Is this possible?

```
        FitnessOptions.builder()
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
                .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
                .build();
```

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Have you seen this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54093789/how-to-differentiate-between-manual-added-steps-and-sensor-recorded-steps-in-goo)?

Comment: Thanks. This appears to be the way to go.